# Apache 2.4 PHP-FPM TCP configuration yields 503 Service Unavailable and permission denied: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect

Tags: php, apache, redhat, httpd.conf, centos8

I have the following configuration in my /etc/opt/remi/php80/php-fpm.d/www.conf file:

```
[www]
user = apache
group = apache
listen = 127.0.0.1:9040
;listen.owner = nobody
;listen.group = nobody
;listen.mode = 0660
listen.acl_users = apache
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
```

And the following virtual host in my site configuration for apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@site2.sysadmin-uat.co.uk
     ServerName site2.sysadmin-uat.co.uk
     DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.sysadmin-uat.co.uk
     DirectoryIndex info.php
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/site2.sadmin-uat.co.uk-error.log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/site2.sysadmin-uat.co.uk-access.log combined

# <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
#  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9040/
# </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_php8.c>
   <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
        # SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/opt/remi/php80/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9040"
    </FilesMatch>
   </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

This is yielding 503 Service Unavailable page and the following errors:

> [Fri Nov 04 18:00:01.058776 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 10881:tid
> 139625418974976] (13)Permission denied: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to
> connect to 127.0.0.1:9040 (*) failed [Fri Nov 04 18:00:01.058815 2022]
> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 10881:tid 139625418974976] [client
> 10.0.2.2:57066] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1

Any idea what it may be?

Switching to Unix socket works as expected.

```
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/opt/remi/php80/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
```

Comment: SElinux issue ?
Try "semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 9040"

Comment: I attempted the above and can see the port is already defined.
``` ValueError: Port tcp/9040 already defined ```